# How to build link between the pages from one Nuxt.js project to another Nuxt.js project within same root folder?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt.js 3 0r Vue 3 based application that contains a structure similar to this:

```
root
 ┣ commons
 ┗ project1
      ┣ pages
           ┗ landing.vue
 ┗ project2
       ┣ pages
            ┗ myHome.vue
```

I would like to access the `myHome.vue` in `project2` from `project1` but am unable to do so using the `NuxtLink`:

```
<NuxtLink to="/myHome"> Home </NuxtLink>
```

I also tried by providing the folder name:

```
<NuxtLink to="project2/myHome"> Home </NuxtLink>
```

Still not working. I have the re-usable components in my `common` folder and `project1` and `project2` extend the `common` in nuxt.config: `extends: '../common',`.

Can someone please let me know how can I build the link between the pages in `project1` and `project2` as per the standard approach?